# Alert or prompt OK not being selected when user hits enter key

Tags: google-apps-script

How can I get the OK button to be clicked when I use an alert or prompt?

```
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("something goes here");
```

Comment: you mean, how can you have the Enter key work like clicking on OK?

Answer (score 0):

The [alert prompt description](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui#alert(String,ButtonSet)) has the exact method to do this.

I'm not going to copy and paste the sample provided, as I feel that's a bit of a waste.

Comment: this will allow you to either display "OK", "Yes/No" or "OK/Cancel", but it will not (as the title requests count "Enter" to work like clicking on OK.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "[alert(prompt, buttons)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui#alert(String,ButtonSet))" or "[alert(title, prompt, buttons)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui#alert(String,String,ButtonSet))"

You can also use the "Enum ButtonSet" in this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/button-set).

However I don't think its possible that we can change it to recognize hitting the enter key as clicking "OK" button in Apps script .

Hope that helps!