# Google Script: ui.prompt, submit by pressing enter instead of click button

Tags: google-apps-script

How can i submit a ui.prompt in Google Script bypressing "enter key" instead of clicking ok?

Code so far:

```
function PromptBox()
{
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var ui=SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var prompt=ui.prompt("Filter op... ", "Geef je filterwoord op", ui.ButtonSet.OK)
  var response=prompt.getResponseText();
  var button=prompt.getSelectedButton();
  var filterTekst = "";

  if (button==ui.Button.OK)
  {
   return (filterTekst = response);
  }
  else if(button==ui.Button.CANCEL)
  {
    ui.alert("Je hebt geannuleerd");
  }
}
```

Comment: Related: [Alert or prompt OK not being selected when user hits enter key](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27047224/1595451)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apps Script Prompt to react to 'Enter', or HTML Confirm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32162579/apps-script-prompt-to-react-to-enter-or-html-confirm)

Answer (score 3):

## Roll your own dialog/prompt

You can accomplish this by rolling your own dialog.  This a templated html approach so you will have to create some files to implement it.  It isn't necessary to do it this way.  It happens to be easier for me because all of the css, resource and script files were already created and I find it easier to create the javascript in a file rather than in a string.

Google Script Code:

```
function showPromptResponse(title,prompt,placeholder){
  var title=title || "Prompt Response";//default used for debug
  var prompt=prompt || "Enter your Response";//default used for debug
  var placeholder=placeholder || "This is the placeholder";//default used for debug
  var html="";
  html+='<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><base target="_top"><?!= include("res1") ?><?!= include("css1") ?></head><body>';
  //html+='<body>';
  html+=Utilities.formatString('<h1>%s</h1>', title);
  html+=Utilities.formatString('<p>%s</p>',prompt);
  html+=Utilities.formatString('<br /><input id="resptext" type="text" size="25" placeholder="%s" />',placeholder);
  html+='<br /><input id="okbtn" type="button" value="Ok" onClick="getResponse();" />';
  html+='<br /><input id="cancelbtn" type="button" value="Cancel" onClick="google.script.host.close();" />';
  html+='<?!= include("promptscript") ?>';
  html+='</body></html>';
  var ui=HtmlService.createTemplate(html).evaluate();//This is a template
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(ui, 'My Prompt');//launch dialog here
}

function loadResponse(resptext) {//This function determines where response is loaded into the spreadsheet.
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet().getRange('A1').setValue(resptext);
}

function include(filename){//used in the template for loading file content
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).getContent();
}
```

Javascript in a file named promtscript.html

```
<script>
  $(function(){
    var input = document.getElementById("resptext");
    input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();//this isn't required since were not doing a submit but it doesn't seem to hurt anything so I left it.
      if (event.keyCode === 13) {//this captures the return keypress
        document.getElementById("okbtn").click();
      }
});
  });
  function getResponse(){
    var responseText=$('#resptext').val();
    console.log(responseText);
    if(responseText){
      google.script.run.loadResponse(responseText);//send response to google script
    }else{
      alert('Invalid or No Response');//response if nothing entered
    }
  }
</script>
```

The res1.html file is this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

The css1.html file is this:

```
<style>
body {background-color:#ffffff;}
input{padding:2px;margin:2px;}
</style>
```

- [Templated HTML](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates)
- [Client To Server Communication](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication)

Comment: This is a piece of art!!! I had to understand that this works with Google Sheets and that you can have several files in the script editor by clicking on "Add file".